# Program to convert a dst file to jpeg

Tags: software-rec, image-conversion

I am looking for a program (preferably free) to convert a DST file to Jpeg (or PNG)

I know DST is an embroidery format and not much else so I don't even know if this conversion is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Embroidermodder](http://embroidermodder.sourceforge.net/) ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.com/search?&q=DST+to+Jpeg&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

[Maybe this is what are you looking for?](http://embroidermodder.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a rather extensive Embroidery IO suite called [pyembroidery](https://github.com/EmbroidePy/pyembroidery) available on PyPi. There's a couple [command line scripts](https://github.com/EmbroidePy/pyembroidery-CLI), and thus you can do the conversion you want.

```
pyembroidery-convert.py myfile.dst myfile.png
```

I don't think Josh ever added the export to an image thing to embroidermodder.